# Convergence test for Harmonic (ish) sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would like  to test the convergence of 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{w^n}{n^{1/3}}$$
Where $w=\exp(2\pi i/3)$

Are there any methods that immediately come to mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test): $\{w^n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence with bounded partial sums and $\left\{\frac{1}{n^{1/3}}\right\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a decreasing sequence that converges to zero. The series converges to the value of a Dirichlet L-function, $L\left(\chi,\frac{1}{3}\right)$, where $\chi$ is a non-principal character $\!\!\pmod{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Dirichlet's Test should do the job.